# Python file upload script not working

Tags: python, file-upload, file-io

I have the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import cgi
import os
import shutil
from stegano import lsb

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

HTML_HEADER = 'Content-type: text/html'

HEAD = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Success</title>
    </head>
    <body>
'''

END = '''
    </body>
</html>    
'''

def main():
        print HTML_HEADER
        print HEAD
        data = cgi.FieldStorage()
        filed = data['file'].value
        fileds = data['file']
        if filed.endswith('.jpg') or filed.endswith('.png') or filed.endswith('.jpeg') or filed.endswith('.tiff') and filed.count('/') == -1:
            #d = open('hello.txt', 'w')
            # d.write(filed)
            # d.close()
            os.chdir('files')
            with open(filed, 'wb') as fout:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fileds.file, fout, 100000)
        os.chdir('../')
        '''
        sec = lsb.hide(filed, data['message'].value)
        sec.save(filed)
        print "Successfully generated."
        '''
        print END

main()
```

What happens is that I don't run into any errors (cgitb doesn't find anything wrong) however, when I go to the directory thats supposed to contain the file It does not contain anything. I got it to work for one time, but when adding extra stuff it failed and I can't get it to work once again. I saw the uploading... at the bottom of the browser one time also, but failed to see any file in the directory. I'm pretty sure this a stupid error by me, but I have failed to see it after 2 hours of search and testing.

Comment: I can't really comment on the CGI stuff, but you need a blank line between the HTTP headers and the HTML data. Ideally, HTTP header lines should be terminated with `\r\n`, but modern browsers will cope ok with `\n` termination.

Comment: I've been told that, but its worked fine for all my projects so far as long as my !DOCTYPE was declared.